# GROUP BY function that returns the first result

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my MySQL query with its result, I want to obtain for each value of 'function' the first result of 'priority', and thus get the result below

However, a syntax of the type "SELECT function, FIRST (priority) ... GROUP BY function" does not exist, do you have any idea how to do this?

```
SELECT
  function,
  priority
FROM challenge_access_rule
WHERE 10 = challenge_access_rule.challenge_id
      AND (
        rule = 'everybody'
        OR (rule = 'friends' AND 1)
      )
UNION
SELECT
  function,
  isRestriction AS priority
FROM challenge_access_user
WHERE 10 = challenge_access_user.challenge_id AND challenge_access_user.user_id = 2
ORDER BY ABS(priority)

-- RESULT --
emitInstance      |  0
emitDeal          |  0
emitDealInstance  |  1
emitDeal          |  100
emitDealInstance  |  -100
vote              |  -100
emitDeal          |  -200
view              |  -200
interact          |  -200

-- DESIRED RESULT --
emitInstance      |  0
emitDeal          |  0
emitDealInstance  |  1
vote              |  -100
view              |  -200
interact          |  -200
```

Thanks,
Bastien

Comment: How about `MIN(ABS(priority))`?

Comment: -200 still occurs twice in the second result list. Is that intended? Why is 100 not in that list? Also: the term "first" is ambiguous if you do not provide a unique sort order. How will you decide which is first when the priority is equal?

Comment: I already tried "MIN (ABS (priority))", it works but I haven't the sign of my priority

Comment: The SQL: ```AND (
        rule = 'everybody'
        OR (rule = 'friends' AND 1)
      )``` is equivalent to ```and rule in ('friends', 'everybody')```. Just saying...

Answer (score 2):

First, I would simplify your current query to:

```
SELECT car.function, car.priority
FROM challenge_access_rule car
WHERE 10 = car.challenge_id AND
      ( car.rule in ('everybody', 'friends') or
        car.user_id = 2
      )
ORDER BY ABS(car.priority);
```

Then, if you want the minimum of the absolute value of the priority, then you can use aggregation and a `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT car.function,
       substring_index(group_concat(car.priority order by ABS(car.priority)), ',', 1) as priority
FROM challenge_access_rule car
WHERE 10 = car.challenge_id AND
      ( car.rule in ('everybody', 'friends') or
        car.user_id = 2
      )
GROUP BY car.function;
```

or a `case` expression:

```
SELECT car.function,
       (case when min(car.priority) = - min(abs(car.priority))
             then - min(abs(car.priority))
             else min(car.priority)
        end) as priority
FROM challenge_access_rule car
WHERE 10 = car.challenge_id AND
      ( car.rule in ('everybody', 'friends') or
        car.user_id = 2
      )
GROUP BY car.function;
```

Comment: Warning: I use a challenge_acces_rule table and another challenge_acces_user that I use both to get priority, and the 'AND 1' after 'friends' will be changed

Answer (score 0):

This code work !

Thanks to Gordon

```
SELECT function,
substring_index(group_concat(priority ORDER BY ABS(priority)), ',', 1)
FROM (
       SELECT
         function,
         priority
       FROM challenge_access_rule
       WHERE 10 = challenge_access_rule.challenge_id
             AND (
               rule = 'everybody'
               OR (rule = 'friends' AND 1) -- 'AND 1' edit after
             )
       UNION
       SELECT
         function,
         isRestriction AS priority
       FROM challenge_access_user
       WHERE 10 = challenge_access_user.challenge_id AND challenge_access_user.user_id = 2
       ORDER BY ABS(priority)
     ) AS toto
GROUP BY function
```